# Java.io.file Не находит файлы и директории в андроид проекте и за ним

Tags: java, android, файловая-система

Вот весь код .
Проект находится `C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\File`

В нем присутствуют такие файлы

```
C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\File\app\wall.png
C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\File\wall.png
C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\File\app\src\wall.png
```

.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public File file;
    File[] paths;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        file = new File("/");
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("Директория");
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("ЕСТь");
        }else {
            System.out.println("НЕТ");
        }
        paths = file.listFiles();
        System.out.println(paths);
    }
}
```

Теперь экспериментирую, если в строке написать

```
1)  file = new File("wall.png");   получаю I/System.out: НЕТ 
и null в paths
2) file = new File("C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/File/wall.png");
I/System.out: НЕТ
I/System.out: null
3) file = new File("/");
I/System.out: Директория
 I/System.out: ЕСТь
I/System.out: [Ljava.io.File;@a79546f0
4)file = new File("");
I/System.out: НЕТ
I/System.out: null
```

В общем как мне положить файл в корень проекта C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\File  и найти его ? Если я запускаю приложение на эмуляторе андроида , а файл лежит в C:\ , то смогу ли я его найти ? Тут на форуме я видел ответы, что находится.

**UPD**
Не знаю, где я это видел, но нельзя в андроид проект положить файл и потом его прочесть. File работает только с файловой системой андроид, а не его проекта. С чего начинается путь файловой системы андроид?
Если я хочу прочесть файл, то положить его придется в assets и то как я понял он не прочитается  как файл,сперва его надо прочитать как поток байтов , а потом уже записать как File, только куда можно записывать ?

Comment: Возможно будет проще, если вы опишите какую задачу вы пытаетесь таким странным способом решить. Ибо да - файлы проекта неизменяемы и все файлы, в которые приложение будет писать должны находится на девайсе юзера, в его файловой системе, не в проекте, не в APK.

Comment: "2) file = new File("C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/File/wall.png");" глобальные пути зло, вы ведь на андроид пишете

Comment: "Если я запускаю приложение на эмуляторе андроида , а файл лежит в C:\ " поидее можно но эмулятор андроида долен смонтировать, читайте в сторону линукса

Comment: "Не знаю, где я это видел, но нельзя в андроид проект положить файл и потом его прочесть. File работает только с файловой @ @ @Turalllb системой андроид, а не его проекта. С чего начинается путь файловой системы андроид?" ваш файл помещен в сам проект? он в jar, apk ? Если да то нужно использовать так  `getClass().getResources(new URL(относительный путь от корня проекта))`

Comment: Перед тем, как что-то делать, почитайте хоть какие-то [уроки по Android](https://metanit.com/java/android/13.1.php). Большинство вопросов отпадёт.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, задача: библиотека на вход требует File. Это File, который будет помещаться на стену в ВК. Так я и хотел из ресурсов взять File. Утром проснулся и понял, что из ресурсов File не взять, а только InputStream, который уже могу сохранить на девайсе юзера, как вы говорите ну или преобразовать как File и хранить в временной переменной и использовать.

Comment: Богдан Панченко, не понял о чем ты, разве этим file = new File("/");  а не создал File с корневым каталогом? Какой старый объект я затираю то

Comment: Богдан Панченко, вот такой ответ в интернете о том, что можно из C:\  для эмулятора андроида взять File и ввел в заблуждение. Мне этого не надо, я просто пишу приложение чтобы установить на андроид девайс.

Comment: Богдан Панченко, А куда я могу положить файл в проект, чтобы потом получить его так getClass().getResources(new URL(относительный путь от корня проекта))  .   это должна быть какая то директория в res ? drawable или assets ? Могу ли я из этих папок получить сразу File минуя InputStream ? и какой объект мне вернет getClass().getResources(new URL(относительный путь от корня проекта))  ?

Comment: eugeneek, это был простой путь, я по нему не пошел ) я сразу взялся писать игру ,листая мельком уроки, когда столкнусь с очередной проблемой. Не лучший путь, зато сразу практика и осознание того, что для чего нужно. После этого вернуться к изучению уроков проще, они значительно легче воспринимаются.

Comment: ВОт немного точнее то что я хочу: Взять из ресурсов File , который потом я уже сохраню в объект  Bitmap. Ведь библиотека требует на вход File, который можно взять из директорий девайса, а я хочу этот File взять из ресурсов

Comment: Всё, понял. Минуя  InputStream из ресурсов мне не получить File, сказано что там объекты не хранятся как File. Тогда вопрос , а что в директориях устройства они как  File что ли хранятся?

Comment: и для чего нужно это и что мне вернет:  getClass().getResources(new URL(относительный путь от корня проекта)) . ps последние два комментария, как вопросы остались, разъясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь искать файлы которые у Вас расположены на компьютере в директории проекта! Это в корне не верно, т.к. структура файлов проекта на устройстве абсолютно другая! 
Почитайте вот эту статью: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php
Надеюсь она прольёт свет на то, где нужно хранить файлы и как получить к ним доступ.

Comment: Вы правы, но ваш ответ не достаточно разжеван для таких как я, но +  комментарии к вопросу и проблема отпадает